# Cannot map property if it does not exist EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It is possible with entity framework that cannot map my property if it does not exist?
Now I have an ID,Name,Surname,Type, table but I have no property Email . EF is mapping the ProjectUser object properties, which has the property that is not in the database. In conclusion I would like to maintain the Email property of the object if it is not the database, but if there is I would like to get the value.

```
namespace Project.IdentityModel.Models {
    public class ProjectUser: IUser<string> {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }//This property no yet into DB.
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `It is possible with entity framework that cannot map my property if it does not exist?` what? Your question is extremely hard to interpret, but if you don't want a  property mapped then add `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "NotMapped" annotation to make sure it won't be mapped :

```
[NotMapped]
public string Email { get; set; }
```